# Python interpreter is not in a environment, but conda reports it is in a environment

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables

I downloaded anaconda very recently and tried it out but it replaced my default python and giving me this error message, when I want to access my default/non-conda python-

```
C:\Users\Aryan>python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I looked at the environment variables, but didn't understand much, here is what they look like-
[image: The env variables]

Any further specifications on my PC or Python version are welcome!
Any help, suggestion, comment and answers are very much appretiated!

Thank You!

Comment: @ShadowRanger That question is from 10 years ago, when Anaconda did not exist. It is incredibly outdated.
Anaconda is by FAR the best way to use multiple Python versions on the same machine (or even if you just want to use a single version, it is better).

Comment: @1313e: The OP doesn't seem to want to run an Anaconda interpreter in the first place, so `py.exe` is the best solution for that case.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The OP is also not asking for running multiple Python versions on the same machine. They are asking about the behavior of Anaconda on their machine.
And again, using `py.exe` is an incredibly outdated method that should not be used on any machine.
This post is in no way a duplicate of the one you connected to it.

Comment: @1313e: `py.exe` is incredibly outdated? It's literally the current standard for Windows, still supported. Anaconda is fine, but it's a major heavyweight distro with a whole ecosystem built around it way beyond "selecting different versions of Python". The OP is looking to run a `python.exe` that is not the one listed first in their `PATH`, which the duplicate covers. Perhaps not an exact duplicate, but it solves the OP's problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger So, if it is not a duplicate, then why is it marked as such?
Also, the 'duplicate' does not cover the problem the OP has at all.
PS: I did not say that `py.exe` is outdated, I said that using it is outdated. Use Anaconda instead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is because Anaconda overrides everything else on your machine that is related to Python.
The default Python you are talking about can no longer be activated in favor of Anaconda's Python.
This is done on purpose.
What is happening here for you is that Anaconda is attempting to use `python.exe` in the base Anaconda environment (as it can reach this according to your environment variables), but you never activated it, thus giving you that exact warning.

Anaconda environments first need to be activated before they can be properly used.
In case of the base environment, you can do this with `conda activate`.